# vim-plug PlugInstall throws PAT authentication error when trying to pull from git?

Tags: git, vim-plugin, neovim

Trying to set up Neovim with some plugins, and when trying to use `:PlugInstall` I keep getting an error for a webicon plugin, have set up a Personal Access Token with git multiple times now but can't seem to get rid of it...

```
- Finishing ... Done!
- vim-prettier: Already installed
- barbar.nvim: Already installed
x nvim-webdevicons:
    Cloning into 'C:\Users\eirik\AppData\Local\nvim\plugged\nvim-webdevicons'...
    remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
    remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
    fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/kya-zdani42/nvim-webdevicons.git/'
- dracula: Already installed
```

There some other way of setting up the authentication I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue previously, I think your problem is just a misspelling as I'm assuming you're trying to get a hold of `kyazdani42/nvim-web-devicons`? Try changing it and run the command again, it should work.

Why it comes up as a PAT Authentication error is beyond me.